# Fourier transform of ${\Pi}_{a}(t)\cos(2{\pi}f_{0}t)$

Tags: fourier-transform

I want to find the following: $\mathfrak{F}[{\Pi}_{a}(t)\cos(2{\pi}f_{0}t)]$ 

I first did: $\mathfrak{F}[{\Pi}_{a}(t)] = 2a\text{ sinc}(2af)$ 

then: $\mathfrak{F}[\cos(2{\pi}f_{0}t)] = \frac{1}{2}[\delta(f-f_{0})+\delta(f+f_{0})]$

So: $$\begin{align}\mathfrak{F}[{\Pi}_{a}(t)\cos(2{\pi}f_{0}t)] &= \mathfrak{F}[{\Pi}_{a}(t)]\ast \mathfrak{F}[\cos(2{\pi}f_{0}t)]\\&=2a\text{ sinc}(2af)\ast\frac{1}{2}[\delta(f-f_{0})+\delta(f+f_{0})]\\&=a\text{ sinc}(2af)\ast\delta(f-f_{0})+a\text{ sinc}(2af)\ast\delta(f+f_{0})\\&=a\text{ sinc}(2af)+a\text{ sinc}(2af)=2a\text{ sinc}(2af)\end{align}$$

I would like to know if it is correct and if there is an alternative way to find the result easier.

Comment: Note that your final result is the same as the Fourier transform of the rectangular pulse. That can't be right, can it? You made a mistake in the convolution with the Dirac deltas. Furthermore, just before the final result you have both deltas with argument $f-f_0$; one of them should have the argument $f+f_0$.

Comment: I fixed the $f+f_{0}$ . Can you suggest a solution if mine is wrong

Comment: Do you know how to convolve functions with a (shifted) Dirac delta? Can you look it up somewhere? (You'll remember it forever)

Comment: Would you mind clarifying your definition of $\Pi_a(t)$? I know $\Pi(z) $ as $\Gamma(z+1)$, but the index $a$ doesn't make any sense, then.

Comment: @MarcusMüller
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangular_function

Comment: @temp8jfhfhf: aaaah, sorry.

Comment: @MattL. is the correct result $a\text{ sinc}(2af-f_{0}) +a\text{ sinc}(2af+f_{0})$ ?

Comment: No, you have to replace $f$ by $f\pm f_0$.

Comment: actually @MarcusMüller, i would like temp8 to clarify the scaling, w.r.t. the $a$ constant.  i don't think that's well defined and, in the rest of it, it seems off by a factor of $2$ or $\frac12$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last line is wrong. Note that you have

$$H(f)\star\delta(f-f_0)=H(f-f_0)\tag{1}$$

for any $H(f)$.

So your last line should be

$$\begin{align*}
&a\,\text{sinc}(2af)\star\delta(f-f_{0})+a\text{ sinc}(2af)\star\delta(f+f_{0})=\\&a\,\text{sinc}(2a(f-f_0))+a\,\text{sinc}(2a(f+f_0))\tag{2}
\end{align*}$$

You basically get copies of your original spectrum centered at $f_0$ and $-f_0$.